# Javascript error uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am using a javascript file called  `pull.js`. It is using for pulldown refresh in Ipad but , when I use that other jquery and javascript stop working? It is giving the following uncaught exception error :

> "
>   Error: uncaught exception:
>
> [Exception... "Not enough arguments"  nsresult: "0x80570001
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)"  location: "JS frame :: pull.js ::
>   anonymous :: line 26"  data: no]
>   "

I am passing the content of this js file :

```
var PULL = function() {
    var content,
        pullToRefresh,
        refreshing,
        contentStartY,
        success,
        start,
        cancel,
        startY,
        track = false,
        refresh = false;

    var removeTransition = function() {
        //content.style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = 0;
    };
    return {
        init: function(o) {
            content = document.getElementById('content');
            pullToRefresh = document.getElementById('pull_to_refresh');
            refreshing = document.getElementById('refreshing');
            success = o.success;
            start = o.start;
            cancel = o.cancel;

            document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                contentStartY = parseInt(content.style.top);
                startY = e.touches[0].screenY;
            });

            document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
                if(refresh) {
                    //content.style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '.5s';
                    content.style.top = '50px';

                    pullToRefresh.style.display = 'none';
                    refreshing.style.display = '';

                    success(function() { // pass down done callback
                        pullToRefresh.style.display = '';
                        refreshing.style.display = 'none';
                        content.style.top = '0';
                        content.addEventListener('transitionEnd', removeTransition);
                    });

                    refresh = false;
                } else if(track) {
                    //content.style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '.25s';
                    content.style.top = '0';
                    content.addEventListener('transitionEnd', removeTransition);

                    cancel();
                }
                track = false;
            });

            document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
                var move_to = contentStartY - (startY - e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
                if(move_to > 0) track = true; // start tracking if near the top
                content.style.top = move_to + 'px';

                if(move_to > 50) {
                    refresh = true;
                } else {
                    //content.style['-webkit-transition'] = '';
                    refresh = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You are missing the radix parameter on your parseInt method.

Comment: @user125697 radix is optional paramneter

Comment: what is line number 26

Comment: @555k That is where the error is coming from, when you fix that it works.

Comment: Handle your error thru try{ }catch(e){ }

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Assigne named functions to variables thus it does not log anonymous.

Comment: Try to add `useCapture ` param to `addEventListener`, for example `false`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: @Amar: Try Touch Punch: touchpunch.furf.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XPC errors don't come from calling a pure Javascript method like `parseInt` (and the radix argument
*is* optional by *specification*, so all those comments are wrong on many counts).

---

You are [missing the third `useCapture` argument](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) on all your `addEventListener` calls:

Here:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    ...
}, false);  //<-- add third argument
```

Here:

```
content.addEventListener('transitionEnd', removeTransition, false);  //<-- add third argument
```

Here:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    ...
}, false);  //<-- add third argument
```

Here:

```
content.addEventListener('transitionEnd', removeTransition, false);  //<-- add third argument
```

And here:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    ...
}, false); //<-- add third argument
```

Note that in a [newer specification, the argument has been made optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-EventTarget-addEventListener). But that doesn't really matter.